# How can killing a Human being and killing an Animal be on the same level?

Tags: animals, smriti, manu-smriti, shudra, prayaschitta

Why does Manu Smriti say that by killing certain Animals one should perform the same penance that must be done for killing a Sudra?

> Manu 11.131 - Having killed a cat, an ichneumon, a blue jay, a frog, a
> dog, an iguana, an owl and a crow,—he shall perform the penance of the
> ‘Śūdra-killer.

Are Sudras so worse as Animals according to Smritis?

Comment: That's what I don't like about any dharma Shastraes. All of them put shudra equal to animals.

Comment: Same here brother @DarkKnight

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Just a question: Do Shudras mostly consist of people like farmers and fishermen, etc.? I am not familiar with the professions.

Comment: @learner, yes but there’s an overlap of farming between Vaishyas and Shudras. We can say the ones who rear cattle, own cowsheds and landowners are Vaishyas. But the ones who do the farming etc maybe shudras thought historically they too held land. But never made a full fledge business per say. Wherever money is involved it’s vaishya. Also shudras include carpenters and sculptors, actors, artists, washermen, barbers (the ones that serve the other 3 I.e. service sector) etc. Some say all the Varna sankara jaati are Shudras only. - no scriptural reference for these, still trying to discover.

Comment: In an another viewpoint one asks: "what is special in these animals that one has to perform the penance of the Sudra-killer?"

Comment: @Archit Thanks, as always :)

Comment: We simply can't apply sudras logic in present day. Because the society system is completely changed.

Comment: Even among the smriti shastras which are meant to be smriti guides, Manu was not universal across India nor universally accepted. Manu is very old, it was meant for another time. It is not veda.

Comment: @DarkKnight - Dharmena Hinah Pashubhi Samanah - One who lives without following dharma is equal to animal, because they too don't follow dharma. Animals also sleep whenever, eat whatever, sex with whomever etc. If a human does the same things, how are they different ? Sethu - Most of your questions seem to be aimed at defending Hindu religion from attackers who say it is anti-shudra, anti-women etc. First realize that by apologizing for your ancient traditions, you're actually losing both dharma and the battle with debaters.

Answer (score 5):

There is this following verse  (11.140) which supports the commentator's interpretation (mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45908/4732)), that when a number of animals have been killed, one must perform the penance of killing a human being viz: a Shudra.

> Manu 11.140. But for destroying one thousand (small) animals that have
> bones, or a whole cart-load of boneless (animals), he shall perform
> the penance (prescribed) for the murder of a Sudra.

In general, the penances for killing men from the four Varnas are mentioned below:

> Manu 11.126. One fourth (of the penance) for the murder of a Brahmana
> is prescribed (as expiation) for (intentionally) killing a Kshatriya,
> one-eighth for killing a Vaisya; know that it is one-sixteenth for
> killing a virtuous Sudra

So, we can't conclude from these verses that Shudras are considered by the Manu Smriti as equal to animals.

Comment: Manu further goes on to prescribe prayashchitt for other animals like horses etc which are much lower than that of these animals, when killed in thousands.

Comment: Yes, noticed that those penances are less severe in comparison @Archit

Comment: @Rickross aren't there legal punishments though? I am confused

Comment: No legal punishments as far as I know @Haridasa

Comment: @Rickross so murder has no punishment to it, are you sure from what I know the king does punishment.

Comment: Murder of animals or humans? @Haridasa

Comment: @Rickross Humans

Answer (score 3):

Medhatithi in his commentary for this verse [says](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202018.html):

> Inasmuch as the expiation prescribed is a heavy one, it should be understood as applying to a **case where all these animals have been killed.**

The purpose of this verse is to enjoin the type of penance that must be done for killing all these animals together.

So, the verse is saying that the penance (prayaschitta) that is to be done for killing a shudra is to also be done when all these animals are killed.

It's not saying that shudras are on the same level as animals.

Comment: These are expiations usually performed to get rid of sin on personal level. Punishment is dealt separately. It can even be death penalty in killing of a 4V.